# Dot plot with column names on x-axis and shape of dots by index names

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have this toy dataframe

```
data = {'Column 1' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
        'Column 2' : [1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=["Apples", "Oranges", "Puppies", "Ducks"])
```

How can I make a dot/scatter plot of the dataframe with column names on the x-axis and the shape of the dots are different based on the index values, something similar to this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use seaborn's scatterplot which supports marker styles out of the box.  Seaborn works easiest with data in "long form", which can be created via `pd.melt()`.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column 1': [1., 2., 3., 4.],
        'Column 2': [1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=["Apples", "Oranges", "Puppies", "Ducks"])
df.index.name = 'Item'  # give the index a name, to be used as column name by reset_index()
df_long = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='Item')

marker_styles = {"Apples": "^", "Oranges": "X", "Puppies": "*", "Ducks": "v"}

ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df_long, x='variable', y='value',
                     style='Item', markers=marker_styles, hue='Item', palette='dark')
sns.move_legend(ax, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.01))
ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot with marker styles]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. Copycatting your code, I didn't reset the index but populate it for the `df_long` to suit my requirements and it also WORKED! According to you, which plotting library is better: matplotlilb or seaborn. Would you please recommend the best book to learn about that better plotting package?

Comment: Seaborn is built on matplotlib.  It is easier to use for many cases. But for fine-tuning, or to implement new plot types, you'll need matplotlib.  To learn more about seaborn, KImberley Fessel's [youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaf4ir8eT38&list=PLtPIclEQf-3cG31dxSMZ8KTcDG7zYng1j) are an interesting resource. For matplotlib, the [online tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html) are quite extensive.